# neural network: in neurons[[i]] %*% weights[[i]] : requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments

Tags: r, neural-network

i am trying to the neural network method on my data and i am stuck. 
i am allways getting the message:

`in neurons[[i]] %*% weights[[i]] :    requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments`

the facts are:

1. i am reading my data using `read.csv`
   **i am adding a link to a file with some of my data, i hope it helps
   https://www.dropbox.com/s/b1btx0cnhmj229p/collineardata0.4%287.2.2017%29.csv?dl=0**
2. i have no NA in my data (i checked twice)
3. the outcome of `str(data)` is:

   'data.frame':   20 obs. of  457 variables:
    $ X300.5_alinine.sulphate    : num  0.351 0.542 0.902 0.656 1 ...
    $ X300.5_bromocresol.green   : num  0.435 0.603 0.749 0.314 0.922 ...
    $ X300.5_bromophenol.blue    : num  0.415 0.662 0.863 0.345 0.784 ...
    $ X300.5_bromothymol.blue    : num  0.2365 0.0343 0.4106 0.3867 0.8037 ...
    $ X300.5_chlorophenol.red    : num  0.465 0.1998 0.7786 0.0699 1 ...
    $ X300.5_cresol.red          : num  0.534 0.311 0.678 0.213 0.821 ...
   continued
4. i have tried to do use model.matrix
5. the code i have was tried on different datasets (i.e iris) and it was good.

can anyone please try and suggest what is wrong with my data/data reading?

the code is

```
require(neuralnet)
require(MASS) 
require(grid)

require(nnet)

#READ IN DATA
data<-read.table("data.csv", sep=",", dec=".", head=TRUE)
dim(data)

# Create Vector of Column Max and Min Values
maxs <- apply(data[,3:459], 2, max)
mins <- apply(data[,3:459], 2, min)

# Use scale() and convert the resulting matrix to a data frame
scaled.data <- as.data.frame(scale(data[,3:459],center = mins, scale =   maxs - mins))

# Check out results
print(head(scaled.data,2))

#create formula
feats <- names(scaled.data)

# Concatenate strings
f <- paste(feats,collapse=' + ')
f <- paste('data$Type ~',f)

# Convert to formula
f <- as.formula(f)

f

#creating neural net
nn <- neuralnet(f,model,hidden=c(21,15),linear.output=FALSE)
str(scaled.data)

apply(scaled.data,2,function(x) sum(is.na(x)))
```

Comment: Without a small reproducible subset of your data it is difficult to say.  Can you try a smaller subset of variables that reproduces your problem that you can post some here?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple things wrong with your code.

1.There are multiple factors in your dependent variable `Type`.  The `neuralnet` only accepts numeric input so you must convert it to a binary matrix with `model.matrix`.

```
y <- model.matrix(~ Type + 0, data = data[,1,drop=FALSE])

# fix up names for as.formula
y_feats <- gsub(" |\\+", "", colnames(y))
colnames(y) <- y_feats

scaled.data <- cbind(y, scaled.data)

# Concatenate strings
f <- paste(feats,collapse=' + ')
y_f <- paste(y_feats,collapse=' + ')
f <- paste(y_f, '~',f)

# Convert to formula
f <- as.formula(f)
```

2.You didn't even pass in your `scaled.data` to the `neuralnet` call anyway.

```
nn <- neuralnet(f,scaled.data,hidden=c(21,15),linear.output=FALSE)
```

The function will run now but you will need to look in to the multiclass problems (beyond the scope of this question).  This package does not output straight probabilities so you must be cautious.

Comment: hello, first of all I need to thank you for answering my question. this brings me to my question  . I am an inexperienced r programmer. I am a chemistry student, and till now I tried handling with my data myself. recently I got stuck. and the clock is ticking. I need a fresh set of eyes, an experienced one, to look at my data. I am dealing with a classification problem 

can I in any way advise in you? or send you my data and problem.

if yes, you can contact me in private at hodayahh@campus.technion.ac.il